# Play a sound file on mediaplayer with button within ListView item in Android with filepath loaded from SQLite

Tags: sqlite, listview, audio, android-listview

I record some sounds and I save them in /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder folder. Then I save the filepath in SQLite database. So when I populate my listview based on a baseadapter in which my getview has the button clicklistener. So far everything seems good. But when I click on button nothing happens. The debugging shows that button finds the position of the proper list item, method which plays the sound finds the filepath but nothing is playing.

```
 public void playSoundItem(int id)
 {

    final String SoundFile = MyItems.get(id).getItemFilepath();
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        //Uri mp4 = Uri.parse(file + "/" + myList.get(soundPosition));
        //Uri mp4 = Uri.parse(SoundFile);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(SoundFile);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare(); 
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I have tested it with uri parsing and again the same thing. The value of SoundFile is:
/storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder/MySound21-04-2015 20:38.mp4 
 Do I have to parse it to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if listview is clickable or not first